# Migrate a 5.0.6 studio project into Worklight 6.1 studio

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Is it possible to migrate a WL 5.0.6 project into WL 6.1 studio.   The project uses dojo, and Cordova.  Initial results are obviously that dojo is not found, and for the java based Cordova code it is not able to find ::import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
          import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;

Apprecaite any suggestions of steps tpo accomplish this migration, or perhaps the best appraoch is to create a new 6.1 project and manually move in the logic from the 5.0.6 project.

Thanks for any helpful advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot imagine for a Worklight 5.0.6-based app with Dojo and Cordova plug-in, to properly migrate to Worklight 6.1.0.x

1. As you mention, Dojo library is missing, which makes sense. Dojo library is a separate entity from the Worklight project. You will need to import it as well.
2. Worklight 5.0.6 is based on some very olden version of Cordova 2. Worklight 6.1.0.x uses Cordova 3.1.

   In Cordova 3, the structure of config.xml as well as the way you call a Cordova plug-in has changed (if memory serves me right), so I suggest that here too you will consult with the [Getting Started training module for creating Cordova plug-ins](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started/#cordova) (also check out the sample project) and verify that in the migrated project you now follow these changes. I believe the migration process should update the config.xml file, but not any code you write... this is not something Worklight can do for you (as this is user-code).

As for the error mesage, I suspect this very much relates to 2 above; take a look at the sample project and see how the Java class (or .m and .h files for iOS) of the Cordova plug-in is done; pay attention to the imports and alike. Compare the two...

Comment: Yes, as a test I copied a dojo project inside of the project since I was not able to get the 5.0.6 project to make ref to the external dojo.  I have reviewed the getting started which prompted me to write this post to get confirmation.  I'll abandon the direct import and try the C&P into the new WL6.1 project.  Thanks.